# Trying to get the response from Twilio after user send the SMS

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, timer, triggers

everyone, a newbie in programming here. I am currently taking coding camp for my summer project and I am creating a final project to:

create the meal reminder (SMS) every morning (timer trigger has to work first before HTTP trigger) --> then, users will type what ingredient they would like to have in their meal --> Twilio will call the food API to send one random recipe to the user's phone.

The only thing that works in the code is the meal reminder every 6.50 AM but next steps don't seem to work to me, not sure what's wrong.
I am kinda lost what to do since I have debugged for like a week with my mentor. Could you please enlighten me on what I should do so I can get a response whenever I type specific ingredient such as bread or rice? Because I use both HTTP trigger to call my food API and timer triggers to give the user the reminder every morning and afternoon.

### Here is my HTTP trigger function:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const express = require('express')
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');   
    const userInputRecipe = (req.query.userInputRecipe || (req.body && req.body.userInputRecipe));

    app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
        const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
        userInputRecipeFromSMS = req.body.Body;
        context.log(req.body.Body);
   // const userTag = (req.query.tag || (req.body && req.body.tag));
   // const size = (req.query.size || (req.body && req.body.size));
    let resultData = await fetch("https://spoonacular-recipe-food-nutrition-v1.p.rapidapi.com/recipes/findByIngredients?ingredients="+ userInputRecipe+"&number=1&ignorePantry=true&ranking=1", {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-key": process.env.foodKey,
            "x-rapidapi-host": process.env.foodHost
        }
    }).then(response => {
            context.log(response);
     })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
    });     
    
    let recipeData = await resultData;
    context.log(recipeData);
    //Show result to response body
    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */      
        //TODO: create objects for needed to show via Twilio API SMS, HTTP Timer trigger etc
        body: recipeData
    };
    // SMS reply to update and fix 
        if (req.body.Body == userInputRecipeFromSMS) {
            twiml.message('recipe please!' + recipeData);
        } else if (req.body.Body == 'recipe yes!') {
            twiml.message('I need that');
        } else if (req.body.Body == 'recipe yes!' + userInputRecipe) {
            twiml.message(recipeData);
        } else if (req.body.Body == "") {
            twiml.message("Oops, this recipe is not available. Try again by sending us another ingredient.");
        } else {
            twiml.message(
                'Sorry, this recipe is not available. Try again by sending us another ingredient.'
            );
        }
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
        res.end(twiml.toString());
        });
        http.createServer(app).listen(1337, () => {
            console.log('Express server listening on port 1337');
        });
        context.done();
    }.catch(err => {
        context.log.error("Twilio Error: " + err.message + " -- " + err.code);
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            body: `Twilio Error Message: ${err.message}\nTwilio Error code: ${err.code}`
        };
        context.done();
    });
```

### And here is my timer function:

```
const fetch = require ('node-fetch')
const twiAccountSid = process.env.TWILIO_SID;
const twiAuthToken = process.env.TWILIO_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(twiAccountSid, twiAuthToken);
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();    
    if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
    {
        context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
    }
    client.messages
    .create({ from: process.env.SENDER_NUMBER,
           body: "Morning! Time to have breakfast . What ingredient would you like to have?",
           to: process.env.RECIPIENT_NUMBER,
           mediaUrl: "https://miro.medium.com/max/700/1*OtRzMDGD0qepGUCToZHZ3Q.jpeg",
       })
        .then(message => {             
           context.log("Message sent");
           context.res = {
               body: 'Text successfully sent'
           };
           context.log('JavaScript timer trigger done!', timeStamp);
           context.done();
        }).catch(err => {
          context.log.error("Twilio Error: " + err.message + " -- " + err.code);
          context.res = {
                   status: 500,
                   body: `Twilio Error Message: ${err.message}\nTwilio Error code: ${err.code}`
               };
          context.done();
        });

        // just try to call my http trigger function 
        async function myMessage(){
            let httpfunc = "https://serverproject1.azurewebsites.net/api/tastyapirecipe"
    
            let resp = await fetch(httpfunc, {
                method: 'GET'
            });

            let data = await resp.json()
            return data;
        }

        let myResp = await myMessage()

        context.res = {
            myResp: myResp
        }
    }
```

This is the error that I get when I test it on Azure portal
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nURZ.png)

I would appreciate if any of you would like to help to figure out what's wrong with it. I will need to present this project in a week later. Thank you!